# Is it possible to do "incremental testing" with sbt and Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sbt

I migrated a large Maven project with submodules to sbt and got it to build correctly with Jenkins and its sbt plugin. I run `sbt compile test`. As I understand, sbt compiles incrementally by default. Is it also possible to have it run only tests affected by the changed classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using `testQuick`, see the [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#testQuick) for more information.